# mysql trigger: insert a new column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem to write a Mysql trigger.

I have 2 tables. First masseges:

```
msg_id   outgoing_msg_id incoming_msg_id    msg_date          msg
501        10001000         123011111       a timestamps    "hello"
```

second Queue:

```
queue_id    unique_id   msg_id
1          12310012      501
```

Everytime someone (user with customer role) send a message to Service user (role SERVICE), it should be checked whether this message is his first message on this day.
If YES:

- I should insert a new row in queue. (there is no problem) I should
  insert a new message row from SERVICE user to the sender. And this is the problem.
  Because I can't insert a new message row in a trigger on message
  table.

This is my trigger:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_count int DEFAULT 0;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count from messages inner join users on outgoing_msg_id = unique_id WHERE outgoing_msg_id = new.outgoing_msg_id and date(msg_date) = date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) and role like "customer"
     GROUP by outgoing_msg_id;
     
     if v_count = 1 THEN -- if this is his first message
     INSERT into queue(unique_id) values(new.outgoing_msg_id);
     end if;
     

   -- insert new message from SERVICE to CUSTOMER to wait?!
END
```

It works. But I don't know how to insert a new role in messages table.

Comment: 1) You do not need in SELECT COUNT and intermediate variable, use IF [NOT] EXISTS. 2) You cannot insert one more row into the table where the trigger is defined on. But you may insert a row into some service table. Then some event procedure (which is executed, for example, each second) will check the service table, and if it is not empty then the procedure will insert needed row and delete processed row from service table.

Comment: I didn't want to use an EVENT. But I think this is the only choice.

Comment: There is another option - use not single INSERT query but stored procedure.